# Default gateway config in FlexFabric 5700

Tags: hp, switch, 10gbethernet

We've taken delivery of a brand new set of shiny FlexFabric 5700 10GbE switches. I've read through the config and setup guides provided by HP and they're great, except that they outright *lie* about configuring a default gateway for the management interface of the switch.

Their recommendation is to use the following steps:

```
system-view
interface m-eth0 
ip address 10.0.0.2 24
ip gateway 10.0.0.1
```

For starters, `m-eth0` doesn't *exist*. So we replace that with the correct interface name: `M-GigabitEthernet0/0/0`

We try that. 
Unfortunately, the `ip` command *has no gateway section*. It only has `address` and `irdp`.

Has anyone run into this issue and if so, where can I find the default gateway settings for the management interface for these things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find this anywhere else so if hopefully this helps somebody

The command is:

ip route static 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 x.x.x.x (IP of default gateway)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for this, saved me some time.  Ended up with this quick setup for basic telnet access (prior to setting up SSH, VLANs and all that responsible stuff ;-P

Assign an IPv4 address to the management Ethernet port:

- {sysname} system-view
- [Sysname] interface M-GigabitEthernet0/0/0
- [Sysname-m-gigabitethernet0/0/0] ip address x.x.x.x 24
- [Sysname-m-gigabitethernet0/0/0} quit
- [Sysname] ip route-static 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 y.y.y.y

Note: Fundamentals Configuration Guide has incorrect commands:

- [boot] interface m-eth0
- [boot-m-eth0] ip gateway 192.168.2.2

Allow and configure Telnet:

- system-view
- [Sysname] telnet server enable
- [sysname] aaa session-limit telnet 1
- [Sysname] line class vty
- [Sysname-line-class-vty] user-role network-admin
- [Sysname-line-class-vty] authentication-mode password
- [Sysname-line-class-vty] set authentication password simple zzz
- [Sysname-line-class-vty] idle-timeout 30
- [Sysname-line-class-vty] quit
- [Sysname] save safely

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, everything above will assign an IP to a M-Gigabit or M-TenGigabit interface.  However, if you're looking to manage the switch, you probably want to specify the IP address on your primary vLAN. So...

> [HP] system-view
>
> [HP] interface vlan-interface 1
>
> [HP-Vlan-interface1] ip address X.X.X.X 24

This set off commands will set the IP address for VLAN 1, which is the primary vLAN on the box, allowing any connected port access to the HTTP interface.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the M-eth0 interface referred to in the documentation appears only when the switch boots to "emergency shell" mode.  This happens when the switch can't find a usable system file.

The documentation is not wrong as this is always mentioned in the "Emergency shell commands" section.  But there is a lack of information about the other M-Gigabitethernet0/0/0 interface and how it fits into the overall routing of the different switches.

Comment: Agreed - the official docs are a bit lacking in that department.